# how to lock method and release it after test

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview

I have tried to lock onclick method after 2 clicks and release it after test/compare betweeen these clicks, I have recyclerview and listener to these click 
is there a way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'locking a method'? What do you mean by 'test' (unit test)? What do you mean by 'compare between these clicks'?

Comment: ok, I will try to be more specific, I created memory game and after to click I compare between two cards (that display in recyclerview and gridlayout), I tried to use synchronized block but it is incorrect

Comment: @yaffa use an `int` variable as counter.. eg if `counter>2 ? ignore : proceed`.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to lock onClick method, write this code:

```
int counter=0; //definite it as an instance variable

public void onClick(View view)
{
  if(counter<2)
  {
    swtich(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.firstcard:
        //do something
        break;
        case R.id.secondcard:
        //do something
        break;
        ...
        counter++;
    }
  }
}
```

Of course you have to set this in the layout for each card:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

And when you want to reset the clicks, you have to set:

```
counter=0;
```